# gamecenter multiplayer game stucks connecting

Tags: iphone, game-center

I want to add a multiplayer mode to my game but there's a problem.
Sometimes it works to connect my iDevice and the Simulator but most times it just stays in the gamecenter screen where it shows "Connecting...". I choose auto-match and the other player is found quickly and the names of each other's account are shown on the screens. But from then nothing works anymore. After about a minute the names disappear again and it just won't connect. Is this a general problem or could the be a mistake on my site?
When it works the gamecenter screen just disappears and the match starts which is as I want.

The gamecenter screen is called by this code:

```
UIViewController  *myView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView *viewHost = myView.view;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:viewHost];
[[GCHelper sharedInstance] findMatchWithMinPlayers:2 maxPlayers:2 viewController:myView delegate:self];
[myView shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```